# “Dear {Ms, Mr, Mrs,Dr, Prof etc} Psmith,” - what do you call the part in braces?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, politeness

> Dear {Ms, Mr, Mrs, Dr, Prof etc} Psmith,

In the example above, how do you name the particle in curly brackets?

I'm writing a questionnaire asking, also, how a person would like to be addressed in future correspondence but it (my question) has to fit in a column header in a table, so the shorter the better.

Comment: @Jasper I like very much your edit, especially the enhanced title. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, you are thanking [@ColleenV ♦](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/9161).  She did most of the editing.  I just added the [tag:politeness] tag.  You can review the edit history by clicking the "edited [time] ago" link.  If you ever need to undo an edit, the edit history will let you "rollback" to a previous version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a "title of address". Forms often refer to it as a "prefix", just as they often call '"Jr", "2nd" etc a "suffix", because a title of address preceds the name in this usage.

Other titles of address include: "Sir", "Lady", "Lord", "Bishop", "Governor", "Senator", "Earl", "General" and many others. A title of address is one that may precede a name when direct;ly addressing the holder.

Note, in US formal usage, "President" is not a title of address, POTUS is always formally addressed as "Mr. President" (or "Madam President" should a female President be elected). However "President" is a title of address in the usage of some other countries, and is informally (or one could say incorrectly but widely) used as such in the US.

There was a debate as to the proper title of address for the US President during the First US Congress. One form suggested was "His High Mightiness", that being the form used for the Stadtholders of the Dutch Republic at the time. It was rejected, at least partly, as I have read, on the ground that a likely candidate for the office was a relatively short man.

There are titles which are not titles of address, such as "minister" (in the religious sense) and "Doctor of Dental surgery (DDS)" and "Bachelor" (in the academic sense). The letters for various academic degrees and orders of knighthood (known as post-nominals) are also not titles of address. The terms  "The Honorable" and "The Reverend" (and the like) are used when sending letters, but not in direct address, and so are not titles of address.

All of the various titles listed above, and most others, are also "honorifics". However it is possible (although now rare) to have a title of address that is not an honorific. "Prisoner" when used in a construction such as "Prisoner Jones, step forward!" is a title of address, but decidedly not an honorific.

Comment: Often (at least in Britain) known simple as a 'title'.

Comment: Also in Britain you can have Sir, Lady, Lord. I suppose in theory you could have Prince or Princess, but I have never seen them available for choosing on forms, whether on the web or on paper. Some very 'woke' organisations might include Mx, which is non-gender-specific.

Comment: @Michael Harvey not all titles function as titles of address, although many, perhaps most do. "minister" (in the religious sense) and "Doctor of Dental surgery (DDS)" come to mind, as does "Bachelor" (in the academic sense). A title of address is one that may precede a name when direct;ly addressing the holder.

Comment: I meant that, as per the original question, I would start a letter or formal email Dear Sir Peter, Dear Lady Smith, Dear Lord Jones, in the same way that I would use Mr, Mrs, Ms, etc. Isn't that what you mean by 'titles of address'? That are also known (although nobody here has said so) as _honorifics_?

Comment: @Michael Yes those are all titles of address, as are "Bishop", "Governor", "Senator", "Earl", "General" and many others. In US formal usage, "President" is not a title of address, POTUS is always addressed as "Mr. President" or "Madam President". Yes these are all honorifics, but so are many tjhings that are not titles of address, such as the letters for various academic degrees and orders of knighthood (known as post-nominals) "The Honorable" and "The reverend" (and the like) are used when sending letters, but not in direct address, and so are not titles of address.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey _"Mx"_??? I wasn't aware of that... thanks a lot